# How to create a private package for just single meteor app?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Meteor 0.6.5.1 from 0.6.4 (my custom private package is ignored and won't load properly)

- How do I get it to load, I've been searching all over and this is becoming frustrating.

I can't seem to get my package that I used to have inside my packages/ folder and added in smart.json:

```
{
  packages: {
    "my_package": {
       "path": "packages/my_package"
     }
  }
}
```

I've also tried using an absolute path as well as moving the my_package outside of the meteor directory all together

Since 0.6.5 upgrade it now says:

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
  Package my_package has been ignored because it has been manually installed in /packages
```

I've also tried:

```
$ mrt add my_package
my_package: no such package
```

Resulting in: "no such package" error, even though it's in the packages/folder

What am I missing!! :)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a `smart.json` file if it is a private package for just this app.  You do need a `package.js` though.  After that, just add the package name to `.meteor/packages`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the underscore in the name "my_package" is what doesn't work. Try renaming the directory with a dash "my-package" (and adding to .meteor/packages) to see what happens.